# Tuple.Create return type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, tuples

Given

```
void foo(Tuple<object> t)
{

}
void bar()
{
    foo(Tuple.Create("hello"));
}
```

the c# compiler returns

```
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'foo(System.Tuple<object>)' has some invalid arguments
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Tuple<string>' to 'System.Tuple<object>'
```

Adding explicit types to Tuple.Create defeats its purpose.  How can I convince the compiler to accept the code?

FWIW, I think C++ doesn't have this problem: http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html#constructing_tuples

Comment: If you don't care about being strongly typed the why not just use a void foo(params object[] args) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same generic type covariance issue that comes up daily. It is simply not possible to convert `Foo<T>` to `Foo<SubT>` or vice-versa. Starting with .NET 4, it is supported - but only for interfaces and delegates, and by explicitly specifying the generic type parameter as variant by declaring it `Foo<out T1>`.

Comment: And it is not supported for classes anyway; only delegates and interfaces.

Comment: @thecoop oops, forgot that bit. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can make the code compile by *not* using `Tuple<object>` but using `Tuple<T>`

```
void foo<T>(Tuple<T> t)
```

If  you don't want to do that, you simply *will* need to be explicit with the string to object in the Tuple.Create method.

```
Tuple.Create<object>("Hello");
Tuple.Create((object)"Hello");
```

Consider if you *could* have `Tuple<object>` and then pass in a `Tuple<string>`. What if your signature was

```
void(ref Tuple<object> t)
```

There's nothing that stops you from writing in that method

```
t = new Tuple<object>(1);
```

And now you've just put a 1 in a tuple that only allows strings. Granted, it's a corner case as Tuple is inherently readonly so you need a `ref` parameter, but it's a problem case, nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to turn a `Tuple<string>` into a `Tuple<object>`, which you cannot do - generic variance is only supported for interfaces and delegate. You need to explicitly specify the type arguments to `Tuple.Create`:

```
void bar()
{
    foo(Tuple.Create<object>("hello"));
}
```